# Css scaling background image when a browser width changes

Tags: css

I have the following html and css

```css
.image-container {
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/GA6bB.png');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 450px;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container"></div>
```

The above displays the image but its not responsive. The image looses certain areas when the page is resized. How can i maintain the image when the browser is resized

Comment: Either use `background-size: cover; height: 450px;` like you did, and have your image cropped. Now your image is stretched to fill 100% width, but forced to 450px height. Check [w3schools: CSS background-size Property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp) if there is another value that fits your needs. If you want to retain the full image you need to loose the `height: 450px`. Another thing: a fixed height of 450px is not responsive itself. While on a 1920x1200 display this may look well, on a 360x720 device it won't. Have you tested this already?

Answer (score 2):

Use `contain`:

```css
.image-container {
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/GA6bB.png');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  width:100%;
  height:450px;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container"></div>
```

From MDN:

> `contain`: Scales the image as large as possible without cropping or stretching the image.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code will solve your problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
.aspect-ratio-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
}

.aspect-ratio-container .aspect-ratio-item {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/GA6bB.png');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  background-position: center center
}
  
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="aspect-ratio-container">
    <div class="aspect-ratio-item"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

use contain:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
.image-container {
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/GA6bB.png');
  background-size:contain;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  width:100%;
  height:450px;
}  
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="image-container"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: After the edit you use 2 times the background-size property, remove the second one.